# Node.js All CSS AND JS Links disappears at a certain route

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey guys i have a really strange issue, and that is that when i go the route http://localhost:5000/posts/edit/<%=idofblog%>  all the CSS styling and Js code is not loaded and i have a very ugly looking web page i have no idea what is going on, all the other routes are working just fine.

All the CSS and Js folders are inside the public folder

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
```

this is my entire file structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqXcx.png)

Inside the _layout folder i have a header.ejs file which has all the links to css like this:- `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/register.css">`

every route is working perfectly but as soon as i go to this route http://localhost:5000/posts/edit/<%=idofblog%> every CSS and JS code is gone and the images as well. 
Inside the posts.js route i have this

```
router.get('/edit/:id',(req,res)=>{
res.render('edit');
```

});
And the href link in the ejs file is this

```
<a href="edit/<%=post._id%>" class="btn btn-info btn-rounded">Edit</a>
```

The page is loaded and everything like the input fields, textarea are there but there is no styling, i don't know what im doing wrong.

Comment: are there any errors in the console window of the browser?

Comment: yes this is it   Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:5000/posts/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js”. but every other route is fine

Comment: can I see you jquery import?

Comment: <script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 

 <script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js"></script>
 <script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <script src="../vendor/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
                       <script src="../js/main.js"></script>

Comment: can you hit `http://localhost:5000/public/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js` and let me know what happens?

Comment: Cannot GET /public/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js

Comment: ok, change your `express.static` to `app.use(express.static('public'));` and see if you can hit `http://localhost:5000/public/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js`

Comment: nope same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but what I see, your problem might be that you are using relative paths to load your styles and scripts. You should use absolute, so for example to load css you need to do it this way(make sure to use path according to your project structure):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/register.css">
```

Comment: if i do this then all the routes don't have CSS

Comment: As I said, I don't know your project structure, so the path that I wrote might be wrong, you have to figure out the proper absolute path for your project.

Comment: i'll figure something out thanks a lot for your help

Comment: got it working just had to replace <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/register.css"> with <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/register.css">